# Layout of the KOMA-Script guide

Tags: koma-script

The [KOMA-Script guide](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguide.pdf) states the following on page 26:

> The literature gives different values for good line lengths, depending
>   on the author. To some extent, this is related to the native language
>   of the author. Since the eye jumps from word to word, short words make
>   this task easier. Considering all languages and fonts, a line length
>   of 60 to 70 characters, including spaces and punctuation, forms a
>   usable compromise.  This requires well-chosen leading, but LaTeX's
>   default is usually good enough. Longer line lengths should only be
>   considered for highly-developed readers who spend several hours daily
>   reading. However, even for such readers, line lengths greater than 80
>   characters are unsuitable.

Yet, the KOMA-Script guide has a line length of > 100 characters. Why is that? Are there exceptions to these rules that apply here?

Similarly, the guide states the following on page 24, which is apparently also violated by the KOMA-Script guide:

> In a single-sided document, the left and the right margin should have
>   equal widths. The relation of the upper margin to the lower margin
>   should be 1:2. In a double-sided document (e. g. a book) however, the
>   complete inner margin (the margin at the spine) should be the same as
>   each of the two outer margins; in other words, a single page
>   contributes only half of the inner margin.

Are there any special reasons for the differences between the claims being made and the actual layout being used in the same document?

An answer I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/268357/is-the-koma-script-documentation-considered-typographically-sound) indicates that the layout of the book is sound while the online version deviates and, further, that "margins have been cut to allow more legible text on the typical computer screen. You can look upon this as a service for the user or as one of the restrictions of the free version compared to the book." Yet, why would longer lines be legible on a computer screen if the following statement from the KOMA-Script guide is true (as mentioned above): "Longer line lengths should only be considered for highly-developed readers who spend several hours daily reading. However, even for such readers, line lengths greater than 80 characters are unsuitable."

Comment: Why aren't you using the author?

Comment: On my screen, the max line length in your question is about 90 chars wide, resulting in huge left and right margins. People tend to fit the pdf to fit the screen width, which would result in really big letters. So, it is a compromise i would say.

Comment: On your first comment: why isn't everybody else contacting authors directly and rather posting questions on stackexchange instead? I mean this is the whole purpose of a Q&A website. On your second comment: that's right but nobody said the question layout on stackexchange was sound in the first place. Most web designers do not have line widths longer than 60-70 characters, and that's for a good reason.

Comment: The thing is, the author seems to contradict himself. People noticed that. The author himself has explained why he did things, you yourself quoted the englisch translation. You still ask. In my point of view, that question is opinion based, the only *right* answer could only be given by Markus himself.

Comment: "to allow more legible text on the typical computer screen." should probably mean "more text that can be seen on screen".

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. Can you give some links to places where I find the author's explanations on why his layout deviates?

Comment: You can also find it in the colophon as mentioned in the linked answer.

Comment: And see also http://www.komascript.de/node/1509 (German)